# onclick upload dropzone jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone, but upload files automatically when dragging, I need to upload files when I click the save button, maybe using onclick is not the correct way

```
<section id="widget-grid" class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="row">

                    <article class="col-sm-12">

                        <div class="jarviswidget" id="wid-id-4" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-custombutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false" data-widget-sortable="false">

                            <header>
                              <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> </span>
                              <h2>Insertar Archivo</h2>
                            </header>
                            <div>
                                <div class="jarviswidget-editbox">
                                </div>
                              <div class="widget-body">
                              <fieldset>
                                <form action="../upload.php" class="dropzone" id="mydropzone"></form>
                                </fieldset>
                                <br/>
                                <footer>
                                    <!-- <button id="clickable">Click me to select files</button> -->
                                    <!-- <button id="btn-modificar" class="btn btn-primary hidden" onclick="modificar()" type="button">
                                        Modificar <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
                                    </button> -->

                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn pull-right" onclick="AgregarPauta()" type="button">
                                        Guardar <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
                                    </button>



                                </footer>
                                <br><br/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
              </div>
            </section>
```

onclick="AgregarPauta()" no working

Js

```
function AgregarPauta(){   

  // pageSetUp();


  // Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
  $("#mydropzone").dropzone({
    uploadMultiple: false,
    addRemoveLinks : true,
    maxFilesize: 0.5,
    dictResponseError: 'Error uploading file!'


  });
```

Upload without using onclick

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Dropzone documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration), you can set a lot of options inside of the plugin. If you want to upload the files after you click on a button, put `autoProcessQueue: false` and, on the button click's action, Process the queue using `processQueue()` method.
Here is an example:

```
   var myDrop;
   Dropzone.options.myDrop = {
        maxFilesize: 5, //MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        paramName: "files",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        parallelUploads: 25,
        init: function () {
            myDrop = this;
            ...
        }
    }

    $('#uploadFiles').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDrop.processQueue();
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    });
```

Also, do not initialize dropzone inside a function that you call on a click event, just initialize it on the page loading